# Problem with simplifying before integration

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone explain to me how did the du = 6y^(-1/3)dy went into the last equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start from $$du=\frac{6}{\sqrt[3]{y}}$$ and integrate, you find that $$u=9 y^{2/3}+c$$ So, the change of variable is more than likely $$u=9 y^{2/3}+4$$ that is to say $$y=\frac{1}{27} (u-4)^{3/2}$$ $$dy=\frac{\sqrt{u-4}}{18}du$$ and then $$y^{-1/3} \sqrt{9 y^{2/3}+4} dy=\cdots$$

I am sure that you can take from here.